# \ContinuedFloat for figure over multiple pages worked in Texshop 12.4 but not in 13.35.24

Tags: floats, texshop

I managed to get a Figure over multiple pages working in Texshop 12.4 using stackexchange's previously answered questions.

Now I changed to Texshop 13.35.24 and the Figures are called 15 (a)-(c). 14 (d)-(f) usw. rather than 10 (a)-(g) as before in Texshop 12.4.

Can someone help me with this at all? Thanks a lot!! :)

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,12 pt]{article}

\usepackage[labelfont={bf},textfont={it}]{caption} %makes figure captions italic

%\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{bbm}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabulary}

%\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}

\usepackage{subfig}

%\usepackage{sidecap}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{verbatim}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{lgreek}

\usepackage{textgreek}



%\usepackage{subcaption}

 % Comment from here
\usepackage[right]{showlabels}
\usepackage{color}

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}

\renewcommand{\showlabelfont}{\tiny\rmfamily\slshape}
\renewcommand{\showlabelsetlabel}[1]{\hspace{-1em}\textcolor{blue}{\showlabelfont #1}}
% to here to get rid of the labels in the margin

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\let\origitem\item 
\renewcommand{\item}{\normalfont\origitem} 
\newcommand{\bolditem}{\normalfont\origitem\bfseries}


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}


\begin{document}

%[...]

\begin{figure}[tp]

\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:t0}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T0_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t10}]{\hspace{-0.05cm}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T10_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t20}]{\hspace{0.05cm}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T20_report}}
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\clearpage 

\begin{figure}[tp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:t35}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T35_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t55}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T55_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t65}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T65_report}}
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[tp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:t120}]{\hspace{-0.55cm} 
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T120_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t147}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T150_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t170}]
{\hspace{-0.45cm}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T170_report}}    
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[tp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:t215}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]
{T215_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t300}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]
{T300_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t360}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]
{T360_report}}
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\clearpage 

\begin{figure}[tp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:t515}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T515_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t722}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T722_report}}
\hfill
\subfloat[\label{fig:t912}]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{T912_report}}
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\clearpage   
\begin{figure}[tp]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:tall}]{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{plot_for_all_time_right}}

\caption{This is supposed to be the caption for all the figures above} 
\label{fig:twospecex}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

As suggested in the comments, I have removed and reordered some items in the preamble. Unfortunately, the problem persists: While I want all pages to be considered as one figure, I get Figure 1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4 on the consecutive pages. In the "Log" window, it says:

> Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after
>   2015 (fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
>   (fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

After commenting that out and deleting the aus file, the problem persisted but no messages in the "Log" window were left.

In both cases, in the "messages" window, I get:

> Process started: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures".tex
>
> Process exited normally
>
> Process started: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures".tex
>
> Process exited normally
>
> Process started: /usr/texbin/bibtex "1stYearReportLinnea1
>   copycheckfigures".aux
>
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary
>   file: 1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures.aux I found no \citation
>   commands---while reading file 1stYearReportLinnea1
>   copycheckfigures.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file
>   1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures.aux I found no \bibstyle
>   command---while reading file 1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures.aux
>   (There were 3 error messages)
>
> Process exited with error(s)
>
> Process started: /usr/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1
>   -interaction=nonstopmode "1stYearReportLinnea1 copycheckfigures".tex
>
> Process exited normally

I tried posting the whole log file here but it is too long. If you let me know which part is essential, I will post that. Alternatively, here's a link to it:

[My log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ange6800q45cpde/1stYearReportLinnea1%20copycheckfigures.log?dl=0)

Thanks so much for helping. Even by discovering the Log-windows, I have learnt a lot! :)

Comment: Please put in a complete MWE.

Comment: Also clear out all aux files etc. and compile twice, more if it says you need to.  How did you carry out the upgrade? TeXshop is the editor and that shouldn't make any difference, but if you upgraded the whole distribution something might have changed

Comment: Your code works fine here, if I put into a minimal document (`article` class with `graphicx`, `subfig` and `placeins` in the preamble).

Comment: Thanks for checking this for me, @TorbjørnT.! It still does not work on my TexShop programme despite including what you've mentioned in the preamble. Thanks for you advice as well, @Chris H ! I have compiled over 100 times and have removed the aux files multiple times without success. Is there maybe something that interferes in my preamble? I will post it here.

Comment: I just realised that the preamble was already there but incomplete. If you spot something in it that could cause my error, I would love some help! Thanks =)

Comment: Well, your version of TeXshop will be completely unrelated to the problem, but the versions of some packages could matter. Can you add `\listfiles` at the very start of your example, generate the PDF, and then add the contents of the `.log` file to your question. Other things: you load `sidecap` and `caption` twice, no need for `epsfig` (`graphicx` is enough). Oh, and you can only `@`-ping one user per comment, so @ChrisH wont have been notified (but he will be notified of this).

Comment: Thank you very much, @TorbjørnT.! Even just discovering the "Log" window has been eye-opening for future work. I made the changes you kindly suggested and reordered some preambles as suggested in the "Log" window. The code version shown now is the up-to-date one. The problem, however, unfortunately persists. I hope the link to my log file will allow you or other more experienced users to find out what is going on... Thanks very much for your help! :)

Comment: @ChrisH, do you happen to have an idea how to help me with this? That would be brilliant as I am really stuck... Cheers :)

Comment: Having never used `ContinuedFloat` or TeXshop, I can offer little be general debugging steps/

Comment: Thank you anyway! :) If my log file helps you identify the problem, @TorbjørnT., please let me know. Thank you!! :)

Comment: I don't really know, but seeing as it works fine on newer systems (for example on Overleaf (which has TL16 at the moment): https://www.overleaf.com/10825656nmjvrxrjzzbv), I guess whatever the problem is, it has been fixed. Is updating MacTeX to the 2017 version an option?

Comment: Amazing!! I finally got the update from OS X 10.10.5 to 10.12.6 by our computing officer today and the problem has just vanished. I.e. You were right, @TorbjørnT. Thank you for your help and patience with this!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments. Software Update solved the problem.